# I'm having trouble calling a method in separate script to play sound

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two scripts. The first one plays a selected sound effect; the second calls a method in the first to play the required clip.

The first script is attached to an empty GameObject and the clips are added to it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlaySound : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] AudioClip[] clips; 
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public float volume = 0.5f;

    void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
    
    public void PlayClip(int snd)
    {
        var clip = clips[snd];
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip, volume);
    }
}
```

The second script includes a declaration and a call to the PlayClip method:

```
    public PlaySound sound; // Script containing PlayClip method.

...

    sound.PlayClip(1);
```

I'm getting an error message to say that sound.PlayClip(1) needs an object reference, but I thought that was taken care of in PlaySound().

What am I not understanding?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that in your code it is not actually `PlaySound.PlayClip(1);` ? The error message you suggests that you are trying to call the method vis the type like if it was a `static` method while it needs an instance reference since it is not

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you explain that to me, as I tried static on the PlayClip method and it generated more error messages. (I'm still feeling my way with Unity. I have a mental block with issues like this.)

Comment: I didn't say make your method `static` .. I said it sounds like the code you show here and the code you are actually using are not the same ... the error means you are currently trying to call `PlaySound.PlayClip(1)` which you can not do since `PlayClip` is not a `static` method -> you need to have an instance of `PlaySound` like in your code above ... as you have it here in your question this code would not produce the compiler error you are apparently getting ...

Comment: Could you include the actual complete error message you are getting?

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TileManager+<CheckMatch>d__24.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/TileManager.cs:258)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <ad3eaa0878d94cbe8e45f9c494d71647>:0)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
TileManager:TileRevealed(TileAction) (at Assets/Scripts/TileManager.cs:211)
TileAction:OnMouseDown() (at Assets/Scripts/TileAction.cs:30)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)

Comment: The error occurs only when PlayClip is executed.

Comment: I don't think you shared the code of `TileManager` .. but please refer to [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What I showed in Script 2 is the relevant extract from TileManager.

Comment: Then it looks like you didn't drag/reference/assign anything in `sound` and it is `null` ...

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how that is so, but I'll try to understand how it could happen when I have the PlaySound script attached to the empty game object and I have provided the sound clips.

Comment: An image of the empty GameObject with script attached is here: https://www.perisys.com/images/Inspector-SFX1.jpg

Comment: the error is not coming from this `SFX1` object but rather from the `TileManager` script where you most probably forgot to reference this `SFX1` object in the field called `sound`

Comment: That seems a likely explanation. I'll give it a go tomorrow. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I'm going round in circles again. I provided this reference for SFX1 in Tile Manager:
```
 public GameObject SFX1; 
```
and to play the sound, this:

```
 SFX1.GetComponent<PlaySound>().PlayClip(1);
```
When the sound was supposed to be played I got the error in the following comment.

I don't know how or why I need to assign the SFX1 variable of the TileManager script in Inspector when I've already provided the reference. Are you able to explain why? Thanks.

Comment: Error message:

UnassignedReferenceException: The variable SFX1 of TileManager has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the SFX1 variable of the TileManager script in the inspector.
UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponent[T] () (at <ad3eaa0878d94cbe8e45f9c494d71647>:0)
TileManager+<CheckMatch>d__24.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/TileManager.cs:261)

Comment: Sounds like you either referenced the wrong GameObect or you are referencing in a different instance of `TileManager` .. but basically it means that `SFX1` is not referenced .. in general I would directly use `public PlaySound SFX1;` and do `SFX1.PlayClip(1);` .. this ensures that you can only reference something that actually has a `PlaySound` component in the first place and rule out that `GetComponent` fails

Comment: I tried that and got a "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object". The PlaySound script is attached to the SFX1 object with the three clips added.

Comment: Again: Make sure it is really referenced in he correct instance of `TileManager` ... to me it sounds a bit like you are looking at the Inspector of a different object than the one the exception comes from ... please add a `Debu.Log("Hello there!", this);` and check how often it is called in the console. Then when clicking on it it will also highlight the object which is logging it

Comment: I did that and the Log said "Hello, there!
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object,UnityEngine.Object)".

Comment: The Debug was placed just before the play sound statement.

Comment: and only once? and when clicking it once did it highlight the correct object where the SFX1 is referenced correctly in the Inspector?

Comment: I double-clicked the Debug statement and it sent me to the SFX1.PlayClip(1) statement, after it aborted.
When I double-clicked the error, it highlighted a Controller object in the Hierarchy that I use for a different script.

Comment: you want to click it only once ... if it highlights an object it means there is the `TileManager` script on it which is throwing the exception

Comment: Clicking once on "Hello there" brings up the controller object in the Hierarchy. Clicking on the error message brings up nothing at all. I suspect there is confusion with object references, but I can't figure out why or how. I need to take a closer look at all the code. Thanks.

Comment: I would rather have a closer look at your controller object and which components it has

Comment: Thanks. It's a sprite controller and used for a separate script that attaches to TileManager. I'll look into that.

Comment: Controller is now SpriteControl.
Looking at the Inspector for SpriteControl, I saw that after the list of sprites, there were two objects: Score Label and SFX1, each of which has its own script attached to it. I don't understand why they are in Inspector. However, I set the SFX1 value to 'SFX1 (Play Sound)', the alternative being 'None'.
When I ran the program, I got an ArgumentNullException with the parameter name given as 'source' (that name isn't in the script). Debug showed that the PlayClips arguments were valid.
Clicking on the error message highlighted SpriteControl again.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, two audio sources needed to be set to avoid the null reference: one in the SFX1 object and the other in SpriteControl. It works now.
Thanks to derHugo for all his help. I learned a lot from his advice.